# How should I store boolean values in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I see three main possibilities for storing boolean information in mongodb:

1. 0 or 1 as a String
2. 0 or 1 as a Number
3. True or False as a Boolean

What are the advantages/disadvantages of each method in terms of storage space used and the speed of queries?

Comment: Why would you use _anything_ other than a boolean (`true`/`false`)?

Comment: wellllllllllllllllllll. short of saying is this a trick or treat. you might treat a null or undefined value as a -1 opposed to true/false. hence a number. but one can find undefined values using $exists in mongodb. so no grt advantage. except you could index undefined....

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`Boolean` is a native field type in [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html) (MongoDB's server-side storage format, aka "Binary JSON"). Booleans use less storage than an integer or string and avoid any unexpected side effects of comparison.

For example, in a MongoDB `find()` query a string of `"1"` will not match a numeric value of `1` or a boolean value of `true`. If you want to store boolean values, definitely use a boolean type.

Comparing the BSON size (in bytes) in the `mongo` shell for completeness:

```
// Number (JavaScript double) - 8 bytes
> var foo = { a: 1 }
> Object.bsonsize(foo)
16

// UTF-8 String - 6 bytes
> var foo = { a: '1'}
> Object.bsonsize(foo)
14

// 32-bit int - 4 bytes
> var foo = { a: NumberInt(1)}
> Object.bsonsize(foo)
12

// Boolean - 1 byte
> var foo = { a: true}
> Object.bsonsize(foo)
9
```

Note: the base size of the JSON object in the examples above (not counting the field values) is 8 bytes, so the difference between the reported `Object.bsonsize()` is the representation of the field value.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a couple of boolean values, than it might be fine to use BSON's built in boolean. But as seen below, each boolean's size is 4 bytes. So if your data is very small (compared to the extra 4 bytes), and/or you have many booleans, you might be better off using an integer bitmap with [bitwise](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/bit/) operations.

```
> var foo = {}
> Object.bsonsize(foo)
5
> foo.a = true
true
> Object.bsonsize(foo)
9
> foo.b = true
true
> Object.bsonsize(foo)
13
```

Comment: As noted in my answer, the BSON size of the base object is 8 bytes (including a single character field name, but not the values); a Boolean value is 1 byte. You can certainly pack multiple booleans into a single integer value using bitmasks, but that does trade index efficiency and schema readability for potential savings of a few bytes. As at MongoDB 3.4, bitmask queries cannot use indexes (upvote/watch [SERVER-24749](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-24749)), so boolean values are also recommended if you plan to include those fields in an index.