# is a good strategy to use bitwise instead of lots of booleans in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, bit-manipulation

Consider that the document has 28 booleans and they all have a name, eg:
 - likesApple
 - likesMeat
 - isVegan
 - ridesBike
...

I am wondering if it is better to replace all of them with one int field and set the bitmask for it.
There is no problem in using bitmask, the only concern is the performance in the database for bitwise operations against the common "== 1" and "== 0".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I store boolean values in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351143/how-should-i-store-boolean-values-in-mongodb)

Comment: My gut feeling says: Do it. ;) Less fields = less storage space = less transmitted bytes = less (de-)serialization effort (which is generally a killer from what I've seen so far). Bitwise comparisons can be expected to be fast. The only thing I would doubt is if indexing helps in any way. So there's a trade-off. Also, with a bitmask-based deisng, you are obviously limited with respect to the number of bits you can encode in your bit mask. Once you need more than 64 different values you'll need a different design. But in general, those things need to be tested against real-life data & queries.